# How to change the color and state of a button

Tags: xcode, applescript-objc

I have a button in the style "Recessed" I would like that when I click on it it keeps its active state with its appearance something I see in applications with Sidebar on macOS, as in the image below, would it be possible to do it? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: The on/off and toggle types will do that, but if you are referring to a Finder window, that is not a button, it is a table view cell.

Comment: @red_menace, Yes, I'm referring to the Finder, is there any way to leave a button with that style?

Comment: @red_menace, Can you help me?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61919189/how-can-i-insert-icons-in-a-sidebar